# Struct overloading with operator ==

Tags: c++, struct, operator-overloading

I writing algorithm for converting roman to integer (Code below) and I got error 'too many parameters for this function', but I need two parameters for my comparison. Does someone know how fix my code?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  class Solution {
  private:
    struct symbol {
      char upperCase;
      char lowerCase;
      bool operator ==(char& a, symbol& b) { // ERROR: too many parametres for this function 
        return a == b.upperCase;
      };
    };
    const symbol one {'I', 'i'};
    // ...
    const symbol thousand {'M', 'm'};
  public:
    int romanToInt(string s) {
    // ...
    }
  };
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should move your class outside the `main` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The left parameter of the operator is the automatic `this` object, you don't need to specify both parameters in the parameter list.

```
bool operator== (char& a) {
    return a == upperCase;
}
```

However, this only allows for `symbol == char`, not `char == symbol`. For the latter, you need a regular function, not a member function. You'll need to declare this as a `friend` of `Solution` so it can access the private `symbol` class.

```
  class Solution {
  private:
    struct symbol {
      char upperCase;
      char lowerCase;
      bool operator ==(const char& a) { // ERROR: too many parametres for this function 
        return a == upperCase;
      };
    };
    const symbol one {'I', 'i'};
    // ...
    const symbol thousand {'M', 'm'};
  public:
    int romanToInt(string s) {
    // ...
    }
    friend bool operator==(const char&, const symbol&)
  };

bool operator==(const char&a, const Solution::symbol& b) {
  return a == b.uppercase;
}
```

Comment: I've added a regular function that allows `char` first.

Answer (score 2):

You'd be better have one overload for `symbol` objects, and another for `char`'s:

```
  bool operator ==(symbol& b)
  {
    return (b.upperCase==upperCase);
  }
  bool operator ==(char& a)
  {
   return a == upperCase;
  }
```

In overloading the equal-to operator, the one and only argument is checked against the current instance (i.e. `this`).